# GeoServer SRS transformation issue?

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, bentley

I try to cascade WMS that is published by different mapping server(Bentley GeoWebPublisher) in epsg:2320 to WMS service as epsg:4326 using GeoServer.

I selected epsg:2320 as "Native SRS". I tried epsg:2320 for "Declared SRS" and requesting the layer from client (to say QGIS and Leaflet) with epsg:4326 hoping that GeoServer will make necessary on the fly transformation based on the request's SRS code. I keep getting "Invalid SRS specified." As an alternative solution I tried to declare "Native SRS" as epsg:2320 and "Declared SRS" as 4326 with options "Force declared","Reproject from native". All alternatives resulted with same error-"Invalid srs specified."

Is it wrong to expect on the fly transformation from GeoServer?

As an additional information, source WMS is provided only as epsg:2320.

Comment: It should work with `native=2320`, `declared=2320` and `SRS handling=Force declared`. If the remote WMS does not support EPSG:4326 that you require from QGIS then GeoServer should know to use EPSG:2320 for the remote server. Does other layers from your GeoServer-WMS work with QGIS as EPSG:4326?

Comment: Other layers are displayed as expected. For example ecw file that is stored as 2320 is  published using Geoserver  and it can be viewed in 4326.

Comment: turn logging up and check the log file for errors

Comment: Checking the log helped. It shows that geoserver is making requests to the source wms server in 4326. Since source serves only in 2320, request fails. No matter which option I select for Declared SRS, all requests are made to epsg:4326.

Comment: Is it sure that the remote server does not include EPSG:4326 as supported SRS/CRS in GetCapabilities which would fool GeoServer? Tell also the version of your GeoSever.

Comment: Do you really find the request that GeoServer is making from your logs? I do not with my GeoServer 2.12 and GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER logging level. But I may have other problems because I am getting these error messages `DEBUG [org.geotools.resources.image] - Failed to clear rendered image adapters field to null. Not a problem per se, but if the finalizer thread is not fast enough, this might result in a OOM
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: theImage`.

Comment: Geoserver version is 2.12.1. GetCcapabilities does not include EPSG:4326. GetCapabilities:
<Map preload="">
<script/>
<Version>2.0</Version>
<CS unitsId="2075" isDefault="1">EPSG:2320</CS>
<Units>
...................
<Extent cs="EPSG:2320" xmin="416911.542326771" ymin="4461374.05602165" xmax="429309.033750592" ymax="4470687.50891348" usemapextent="0"/>

Comment: Logging is set as: DEFAULT_LOGGING.properties.

Failed to execute request http://......:.../....?SERVICE=WMS&LAYERS=......&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&HEIGHT=12&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&REQUEST=GetMap&WIDTH=22&BBOX=29.02134627384218,40.28105982699231,29.168318488306042,40.36606430251883&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:4326&VERSION=1.1.1(I removed some parts of the request)

Comment: What you are pasting is not a capabilities document, there is no <Map> element in it. Here is an example of what a capabilities document look like:  https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities
Also, notice that a CRS for being declared as usable does not need to be in the <Layer> section, it could be in the containing Layer too (inheritance)

Comment: Actually I tried to paste whole GetCapabilities result, but It was too long and stackexchange did not accept it as comment. I should have mentioned that. Above commnet contains only parts related to srs definitions in GetCapabilities. To make clear, there is not srs definition in source GetCapabilities except epsg:2320.

Comment: @senolozgur Don't include new information in comments, but please edit the question and put the information there. Then there's no issue with it being too long for a comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: problem is partially related with Geoserver. Source wms layer is served as part of GroupLayer which does not have any srs definition.Like this(part of the GetCapabilities):

```
<GroupLayer>
<Name>PLAN_5000</Name>
<Title/>
<Id>6c288387-5abf-4538-8e66-10dee5816321</Id>
<Description/>
<GetMapRequests>1</GetMapRequests>
<Layer>
<Name>OVAAKCA</Name>
<Title/>
<Id>56d821b6-1ff2-40ac-8a2d-c944a32e9763</Id>
<Description/>
<DisplayOrder>1</DisplayOrder>
<Source>51d48854-01b2-484c-bdb1-7580f06eafad</Source>
<CS/>
<Extent cs="EPSG:2320" xmin="416911.542326771" ymin="4461374.05602165" xmax="429309.033750592" ymax="4470687.50891348" usemapextent="0"/>
```

I ***guess*** that without srs definiton for layer group things get messed up and Geoserver starts to make request in 4326.

When we moved source layer outside of layer group requests started to go as 2320 to the source server. New GetCapabilities contains same layer as (part of the GetCapabilities):

```
<Layers>
<Layer>
<Name>Deneme</Name>
<Title/>
<Id>acc27d2f-e427-44b4-8546-32650d2bc663</Id>
<Description/>
<DisplayOrder>0</DisplayOrder>
<Source>28081abc-4cc6-45af-bd90-923939c8572e</Source>
<CS/>
<Extent cs="EPSG:2320" xmin="416911.4092" ymin="4461373.956" xmax="429308.8587" ymax="4470687.3008" usemapextent="0"/>
```

In this configuration, source layer is under `<Layers>`, not `<GroupLayer>`.

In case of similar error, source configuration can be checked.

Comment: Hum... in a compliant GetCapabilties response there is no <GroupLayer> element either, a group of layers is expressed as a <Layer> containing other <Layer> objects.

Comment: Probably it is vendor specific option of Bentley's GeoWebPublisher. We try to plublish .dgn files.